# Is there a local copy of open ssh session files in VSCode where one can recover a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I had a Remote SSH session going on an AWS EC2 server.  It crashed before I committed changes.  The files showed locally in VS Studio still as it showed it was attempting to connect.  Working through the prompts, the session cleared.

Then, I couldn't connect to the AWS EC2 server.  Are the files somewhere on my local PC to be retrieved?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Why do you not try reconnecting to the server? Where were the files? On the EC2 or on your machine? Connecting to the EC2 instance again would be the best possible option in this case. Why can't you reconnect?

Comment: The files were on the server and backed up to Github, but the repository had grown out of date.  The server started intermittently locking up when I'd compile a Dotnet webapp.  I would have to stop it entirely and bring it back up.  It eventually just wouldn't respond.  Unfortunately, I didn't take a snapshot of it.  I'm just a hobbyist dumbing my way into web app hosting on AWS.   The bummer was I had a list of 233 Maker tips on it I had been accumulating I'd like to resurrect.

Comment: Ah - so no EC2 instance, and you want to see if you can gain access to files you previously accessed?

Comment: This is why the first rule of git is to commit frequently or at the very least have snapshots of the EC2 instance! Expensive lesson unfortunately - check to see if there’s  anything in your app data folder or your temp folder? Recents list in VSCode?

Comment: I tried searching and clicking on the appdata files, but no luck.  It's weird because when I first open VSCode, it typically shows me the last files I was working on even before it connects, so you'd think it would be somewhere on the drive.  Maybe its encrypted.